# How do I set up legacy bootable usb in Paragon's partition program?

Tags: windows, partitioning, paragon

I have paragon hard disk manager basic 16.5

It has an option to create rescue media. I am making the rescue usb right now from a laptop running windows 10.

It asks where the ADK is I pointed it to here C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10 and installed the WinPE addon and it made the ISO and I wrote the ISO with Rufus.

But the ISO contents is clearly for UEFI e.g. there's an EFI directory on the USB.

I am on a laptop whose 'motherboard firmware' setup only has one mode 'legacy'. It doesn't do UEFI stuff. It has no legacy vs UEFI setting.

Maybe an early WinPE might be suitable for a 'BIOS' or motherboard firmware running legacy mode, but i'm not sure how to get the rescue media to be made with an early WinPE.

Comment: ramhound's answer led me to see it was a rufus setting.. needed to set to BIOS/CSM/(ie legacy) in rufus.  The EFI directory remained but was no issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> am on a laptop whose 'motherboard firmware' setup only has one mode 'legacy'. It doesn't do UEFI stuff. It has no legacy vs UEFI setting.

The WinPE image you have created should support both UEFI and Legacy, since the default WinPE ISO supports both, Paragon would have to go to a great deal of effort to remove that support.

> Maybe an early WinPE might be suitable for a 'BIOS' or motherboard firmware running legacy mode, but I'm not sure how to get the rescue media to be made with an early WinPE.

All supported versions of WinPE ISO support UEFI (GPT) and Legacy (MBR).  This includes the Windows 7, Windows 8, and Windows 10 WinPE ISO.  **You will have to look at the requirements for the Paragon WinPE to determine which versions of the Windows ADK it actually supports.**

> I am on a laptop whose 'motherboard firmware' setup only has one mode 'legacy'. It doesn't do UEFI stuff. It has no legacy vs UEFI setting.

It is not clear if the reason you are asking is due to the existence of the EFI directory, or if the media you created, simply didn't work on your machine.  If the installation media did not work then you will be unable to use it on the machine you describe.

Comment: @barlop - I have created my own WinPE image in the past on systems that supported both UEFI (GPT) and Legacy (MBR).  Since the process to create the actually installation media is neither the reasonability of Paragon (unless their software can create it) or Microsoft there isn't any documentation I can point to, that confirms my knowledge of this particular factoid.